# Custom theme not working

Tags: java, android

I have read guides for creating a style and I have created it like below in style.xml

I have imported a custom image and added it in mainfest android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" but still it won't show my theme when I start the app.

This is my `style.xml`

```
<resources>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/images</item>
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/images</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

and this is my mainfest file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="imamalsajadsayings.android.com"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1"
          android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:allowBackup="true"
             android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" > 


     <activity android:name="imamalsajadsayings.android.com.MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />”
  </application>

   </manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not included in theme

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
```

Should be so:

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
```

Also, if you set your theme for **application**, then you don't need to set it also for activities.

Unless different activities have a different theme (so, you specify a different theme only on those ones)

Comment: actually the OPs way is correct, the declared color is now an application resource and can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the theme from your `Activity` by calling `Activity.getTheme().dump()`.
That way you will know what exactly has gone wrong(maybe the theme is applied, but the window background is concealed under the container view's background drawable). I cannot see why the theme wouldn't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem:

you are adding a drawable as a color resource

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@drawable/images</item>
```

this should contain a color value or a color resource like

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">#ffffff</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
```